# Correct use of range(), why does pylint complain: range built-in referenced when not iterating

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

Using range() instead of eg a list can be quite convenient and to the point, but pylint emits a warning if range() is assigned to a variable. (range-builtin-not-iterating)

range objects are list like (have a length, can be random accessed, are iterable etc), so are there situations where this code is wrong?

```
from typing import *

def fn(a: Sequence[int]) -> None:
    for x in a:
        print(x)

r = range(10, 100)

fn(r)
```

edit (added):

One motivation for doing this is to pass the range instead of passing a (start, end) pair all over the place

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, it's just not very Pythonic

Comment: Can I ask you to elaborate on that?  IMHO it is concise, takes advantage of the language and efficient (compared to ie `tuple(range(10,100))`)

I could even (actually, I think it would have been better) to let the type of a be `Sequence[int]` instead of Iterable

Comment: There are people on here that are much more knowledgeable than me about this, but my sense is that you're creating a range, and then creating a function to iterate over it. Why not just create it in the function? A range's only use is when it's being iterated over.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander what isn't pythonic about it? Using `range` objects where you want a `range` object is perfectly Pythonic. I'm inclined to say, just ignore pylint.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander no, a `range` is a *container*. It has more uses than just iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that pylint is not justifying this warning correctly.

The justification on the [official](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html) doc

> (returns an iterator in Python 3)

is right for iterator (such as map) but not for range.

To see the different easily between a `iterator` object and a `non-iterator` object you can execute the following lines

```
r = range(5)
print(list(r)) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(r)) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
m = map(int, '01234')
print(list(m)) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(m)) # []
```

The `iterator` consumed the elements.

However I do not think this is a good practice because you might be tempted to use it as a list, which might be slower in some cases.

let's take those 2 examples

```
r = range(500000)
l = list(r)

%%time
for i in range(200):
    for k in r:
        pass
# 6.7 sec on my computer

%%time
for i in range(200):
    for k in l:
        pass

# 4.5 sec on my computer
```

The main difference is that `list` are load in memory which is faster to iterate over.

Edit: If you are looking for speed you might want to use list, otherwise maybe you should use range.

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2797) on pylint earlier today, if this is worth a pull request, I will handle it later

Comment: Not trying to be difficult or anything, but "As `range` are not memory consuming you should definitely avoid stocking them in variables".. Why?

Interesting to see list is faster (I would have guessed the opposite, especially if the values where actually accessed). oth, if we're chasing memory load - the range would be beneficial..

Comment: `range` does **not return an iterator** If this is the justification in pylint, then pylint is dead-wrong. In any event, there is nothing wrong with using a `range` object like a container. Yes, you are trading *slightly less* faster iteration for potentially *enormous* memory savings (and other nice things, like constant-time membership checking and slicing)

Comment: @ttyridal By this I would say it would be better to define them on the fly each time. But you might be right. I will edit My answer :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I totally agree with you, updated